# Remove value from a List

Tags: c, list, pointers, singly-linked-list

I'm writing a program which creates lists, print it and remove from the list (3 functions).

Print and pushBack are fine, they work nice but I can't figure out how to pick up a number to remove from the list in removeFromList() function.

Don't pay attention on names (like client, socket), it's for my client-server application to save active sockets (that's why I need to remove them from a list when client has disconnected).

Here I have 2 structures: listElement and clientList (which contains a pointer to head element of listElement)

```
struct listElement
{
    SOCKET socket;
    struct listElement* next;
};

struct clientList
{
    listElement * head;
};
```

My pushBack function:

```
int pushBackСlient(struct clientList* list, int socket)
{
    struct listElement* newClient = (struct listElement*)malloc(sizeof(struct listElement));
    struct listElement* currentElement = list->head;
    newClient->socket = socket;
    newClient->next = 0;
    do
    {
        // IT'S PUSHBACK
        if (list->head == 0)
        {
            list->head = newClient;
            break;
        }
        while (currentElement->next != 0)
        {
            currentElement = currentElement->next;
        }
        currentElement->next = newClient;
    } while (false);

    return 0;
}
```

My print:

```
void print(struct clientList* list)
{
    struct listElement* currentElement = list->head;
    while (currentElement != 0)
    {
        printf("%d\n", currentElement->socket);
        currentElement = currentElement->next;
    }
}
```

And the function I have a problem with (I made debug messages to see if a "socket" was added correctly). I suppose I don't need the first 3 lines but not sure.

**Updated**13/05/2017

```
void removeFromList(struct clientList* list, int socket)
{
    struct listElement* currentElement = list->head;
    do
    {
        if (list->head == 0)
        {
            return;
        }

        while (currentElement != 0 && currentElement->next != 0)
        {
            if (currentElement->socket == socket)
            {
                printf("currentElement == %d\n", currentElement);
                currentElement = currentElement->next;
                printf("currentElement == %d\n", currentElement);
                free(currentElement);
                //break; // if I only want to remove the first socket?
            }
            currentElement = currentElement->next;
        }
    } while (false);
}
```

Thank you.

Comment: Your first and most important error is thinking this is C!

Comment: Is this a class (study) exercise?  If not just use `std::list`.

Comment: @Olaf I didn't understand why you're telling that. I'm also using stdio.h, stdlib.h and winsock2.h libraries

Comment: @RichardCritten It's a test task but I need it for my project in clean C.

Comment: @George Z.  Make a choice between C and C++. If it is a C++  program then use the operator new instead of malloc. If it is a C program then use free instead of delete.

Comment: @George Z.  Also it is not clear whether you want to remove only one node with the given socket or all nodes with the given socket.

Comment: @GeorgeZ.: The libraries you use don't matter; Your code does not compile as C, but is C++ apparently! They are different languages. Stop using the wrong language tag!

Comment: @AntoJurković Don't edit to wrong tags! Read the code before editing!

Comment: @VladfromMoscow It's C, I didn't know that delete is C++ function. Got it, thanks.

I want to remove only one element (in my project it will be a socket) from a list.

Comment: @VladfromMoscow I have eddited the question with my new remove() function asRuiSilva suggested in the answer. It can't delete socket. I checked in debug mode: it gets socket values to currentElement but then  it's changed for the next value in the list and no remove. What is wrong? Thank you guys

Comment: @GeorgeZ. See my answer.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The function `removeFromList` is wrong at least because this condition of the while statement can be equal to false when the list contains only one element. In this case even this one element contains the target vakue it will not be removed.

```
while (currentElement != 0 && currentElement->next != 0)
```

The functions can look as it is shown in the demonstrative program.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

typedef int SOCKET;

struct listElement
{
    SOCKET socket;
    struct listElement *next;
};

struct clientList
{
    struct listElement *head;
};

int pushBackClient( struct clientList *list, SOCKET socket )
{
    struct listElement *newClient = malloc( sizeof( struct listElement ) );
    int success = newClient!= NULL;

    if ( success )
    {
        newClient->socket = socket;
        newClient->next   = NULL;

        struct listElement **current = &list->head;

        while ( *current != NULL ) current = &( *current )->next;

        *current = newClient;
    }

    return success;
}


int removeFromList( struct clientList *list, SOCKET socket )
{
    int success;

    struct listElement **current = &list->head;

    while ( *current != NULL && ( *current )->socket != socket ) 
    {
        current = &( *current )->next;
    }

    if ( ( success = *current != NULL ) )
    {
        struct listElement *tmp = *current;
        *current = ( *current )->next;

        free( tmp );
    }

    return success;
}

void print(struct clientList *list)
{
    for ( struct listElement *current = list->head;
          current != NULL;
          current = current->next )
    {         
        printf( "%d ", current->socket );
    }
}

int main(void) 
{
    const int N = 10;
    struct clientList list = { NULL };

    for ( int i = 0; i < N; i++ ) pushBackClient( &list, i );

    print( &list );
    putchar( '\n' );

    for ( int i = 0; i < N; i++ )
    {
        if ( i % 2 == 0 ) removeFromList( &list, i );
    }

    print( &list );
    putchar( '\n' );

    for ( int i = 0; i < N; i++ )
    {
        if ( i % 2 == 1 ) removeFromList( &list, i );
    }

    print( &list );
    putchar( '\n' );

    return 0;
}
```

The program output is

```
0 1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9 
1 3 5 7 9
```

You need at least to add a function that will free all elements of the list.

Comment: Thanks a lot, it perfectly works. Yesterday I wrote almost the same function and it also works. Thank you for attention to my problem :)

Answer (score 0):

For your remove function I suggest something like this:

```
void removeFromList(struct clientList* list, int socket)
{
    struct listElement* aux, prev;
    if(list->head == 0)
        return;

    aux = list->head;
    prev = aux;

    while(aux != 0){
        if(aux->socket == socket) {
            prev->next = aux->next;
            free(aux);
            break; // if you only want to remove the first socket
        }
        prev = aux;
        aux = aux->next;    
    }
}
```

As for your list structure, I suggest using a structure of structs, like follows:

```
struct list
{
    int numberOfElements;
    NODE * first;
} LIST;

struct node
{
    ELEMENT * info;
    NODE * prev; // If you want to have a double connection between the nodes
    NODE * next;
} NODE;

struct element
{
    int id;
    /* Other Properties */
} ELEMENT;
```

It should give you a better control of your list.

Comment: Thank you for the suggestion and for your function. I'm a little (not even a little) confused usingmy structures so I'd like to leave it in its state now :) I aprreciate your help.
As regards remove() function - I've edited my question. I've got a problem with debugging. It seems I can't get a correct socket I want to remove from the list. And didn't actually get what to dowith the first element in the list. Thanks

Comment: @GeorgeZ. I'm just happy to have been useful. Did you solve your problem?

Comment: Not really. I did smth wrong, sockets still can't be removed. I checked in debug mode: it gets socket values to currentElement but then it's changed for the next value in the list and no remove.

Comment: Do you have any ideas how to fix my new function? Dubugging is saying "memory read error". I suppose it tries to read the memory after free() and finds nothing

Comment: In the first place you will never read the last element of your list, because your "if" states that you shall only analyze the element that is not 0 and that has a next element that is not 0. In second place, why do you use a while(false). It is useless. It will run the body code, only once.